# How to connect to BLE device that isn't advertising service UUID in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I am trying to connect an ESP32 module to my iPhone via BLE and am using `centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [carServiceCBUUID], options: nil)` where `let carServiceCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "c0de0001-feed-f00d-c0ff-eeb3d05ebeef")`. I am following Ray Wenderlich's heart monitor tutorial but since the ESP32 bluetooth module is not advertising the main Service UUID, it won't find the device when I do `scanForPeripherals`. Attached is the screenshot of the LightBlue information on the BLE device. Is there a way I can change the advertising data so I can advertise the service? I am running this code on the ESP32 https://thejeshgn.com/2018/06/11/esp32-ble-building-an-echo-service-gatt-server/

[screenshot of LightBlue connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlD9D.png)

Comment: The issue is not on the Swift. If you don't publicly advertise the service, you can't find it that way. You need to do `centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)`. I guess that `BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();` is the where you might want to explicitly advertise the service.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation of `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1518986-scanforperipheralswithservices?language=objc) the `serviceUUIDs` parameter can be `nil` - in that case

> all discovered peripherals are returned regardless of their supported services (not recommended)

So unless you are planning to use background modes to scan when app is in background, you can just pass `nil` as `serviceUUIDs` parameter